# Need help in adding 2 dataframes vertically in scala spark

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, concatenation

i need help in scala spark.
both data frames are created from some hive table and the dataframe is created like the below.
how can i combine both unrelated dataframes into 1 single file?

```
Dataframe1
record1 type basic customer
record2 type special customer
record3 role Manager

Dataframe2
how are you
All the best 
Congratualations
```

Result:

```
record1 type basic customer  how are you
record2 type special customer All the best a
record3 role Manager  Congratualations
```

i have tried converting the dataframe into Array of string with collect() method and tried to combine the 2 array of strings  using concat method but i am getting only the merge result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use row_number over a window ordered by the column you need. That will create an id in each dataframe which you can use to join both dataframes:

**INPUT**

Dataframe 1

```
+----+----------------+
|  c1|              c2|
+----+----------------+
|type|  basic customer|
|type|special customer|
|role|         Manager|
+----+----------------+
```

Dataframe 2

```
+----+----------------+
|  c1|              c2|
+----+----------------+
|type|  basic customer|
|type|special customer|
|role|         Manager|
+----+----------------+
```

**GENERATING IDS**

```
val w1 = Window.partitionBy().orderBy("c2")
val df1Row = df1.withColumn("id", row_number.over(w1))

+----+----------------+---+
|  c1|              c2| id|
+----+----------------+---+
|role|         Manager|  1|
|type|  basic customer|  2|
|type|special customer|  3|
+----+----------------+---+

val w2 = Window.partitionBy().orderBy("c1")
val df2Row = df2.withColumn("id", row_number.over(w2))


+----------------+---+
|              c1| id|
+----------------+---+
|    All the best|  1|
|Congratualations|  2|
|     how are you|  3|
+----------------+---+
```

**JOINING AND OUTPUT**

```
df1Row.join(df2Row, "id").show
+---+----+----------------+----------------+
| id|  c1|              c2|              c1|
+---+----+----------------+----------------+
|  1|role|         Manager|    All the best|
|  2|type|  basic customer|Congratualations|
|  3|type|special customer|     how are you|
+---+----+----------------+----------------+
```

Comment: You're welcome, please accept the answer so any other users with the same issue can found it

Comment: im unable to upvote this using my own id. how to accept the  solution? like any other option

Comment: hi Team, this doesnt seem to be working with more amount of data. the